# Efficient way to calculate standard deviation / volatility of multiple portfolios with numpy multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I am looking for an efficient/fast method to calculate the volatility/standard deviation of several weithings/portfolios with a multi-dimensional numpy array

I have a multidimensional numpy array of covariances, i.e. cov_3d with shape 260,5,5
For each of the 260 cases, i have 10 weightings of the 5 assets, i.e. weights_3d with shape 260,10,5

With the numpy Einstein summation, I can calculate the 260s 10x10 covariances and the extract the diagonal matrix.

Since, I only need the diagonal matrix, a faster, more efficient way should exist such that I can omit the upper and lower matrix calculation.

```py
import numpy as np

# observations just for covariance matrix
observations_3d = np.random.normal(size=(260,5,200))

#260 covariance matrix for 5 assets
cov_3d = np.einsum('nij,njk->nik', observations_3d, observations_3d.transpose([0,2,1]))/(200-1)

#for each 260 cases, 10 weightings of the 5 assets
weights_3d  = np.random.uniform(size=(260,10,5))

print(weights_3d.shape) #260x10x5

print(cov_3d.shape) #260x5x5

#aim: calculate standard deviation/volatility of the 10 weightings/portfolios for each of the 260 cases

#now, its gets ugly
wCovw_3d = np.einsum('nij,njk->nik',weights_3d,  np.einsum('nij,njk->nik', cov_3d, weights_3d.transpose([0,2,1])))

print (wCovw_3d.shape) #260x10x10

std_3d = np.diagonal(wCovw_3d,axis1=1,axis2=2)**.5
```

[image]

Output should be v with the elements defined as above for T = 1,...,260 and P = 1,...,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could directly go there -

```
std_3d = np.einsum('nij,njl,nil->ni',weights_3d, cov_3d, weights_3d)
```

**The progression leading upto that was -**

Starting off with -

```
wCovw_3d = np.einsum('nij,njk->nik',weights_3d,  np.einsum('nij,njk->nik', cov_3d, weights_3d.transpose([0,2,1])))
```

Simplify the transpose part -

```
wCovw_3d = np.einsum('nij,njk->nik',weights_3d,  np.einsum('nij,nkj->nik', cov_3d, weights_3d))
```

Bring that to one einsum call -

```
wCovw_3d = np.einsum('nij,njl,nkl->nik',weights_3d, cov_3d, weights_3d)
```

Since, we are interested in the diagonal ones off the final output, we can equate the diagonal strings (i and k) and hence, get the final expression -

```
std_3d = np.einsum('nij,njl,nil->ni',weights_3d, cov_3d, weights_3d)
```

Don't forget to append that `**.5` part at the end.

---

Alternatively, with `np.matmul` -

```
p1 = np.matmul(weights_3d,cov_3d)
std_3d_out = np.matmul(p1[...,None,:],weights_3d[...,None])[...,0,0]
```

With the equivalent @ operator on Python 3.x -

```
((weights_3d@cov_3d)[...,None,:]@weights_3d[...,None])[...,0,0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation of einstein sum with more than 2 arrays, and the simplification. Both methods are nearly two times faster 5.0 vs. 5.2 vs. 8.9 seconds for 10000 replications.